# Nuxt 3 API call with data from another API call

Tags: javascript, fetch, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am building a weather forecast app and to get data for a specific city I have a dynamic URL (/forecast/[id]) with the city id from [open-meteo](https://open-meteo.com/en/docs/geocoding-api). To get the actual lat and lon I want to make an API call to the open-meteo geocoding API to then use the retrieved lat and lon and timezone to make another request to the open-meteo forecast API. But unfortunately I was unable to make it work.

here is my current code:

```js
<script setup>
const route = useRoute()
const id = route.params.id
const lat = ref(null)
const lon = ref(null)
const timezone = ref("")

const {data: locationdata} = await useAsyncData("geocode", () =>
  $fetch(`https://geocoding-api.open-meteo.com/v1/get?id=${id}`)
).then((res) => {
  lat.value = res.data.value.latitude
  lon.value = res.data.value.longitude
  timezone.value = res.data.value.timezone
})


const { data: weatherdata, pending } = await useAsyncData("weatherdata", () =>
  $fetch(`https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=${lat}&longitude=${lon}&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,surface_pressure,precipitation,weathercode,windspeed_10m,winddirection_10m,windgusts_10m&current_weather=true&windspeed_unit=kn&timezone=${timezone}`)
).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
</script>
<template>
<pre><code>{{weatherdata}}</code></pre>
</template>
```

and this is the error I am getting in the terminal:

```
[nuxt] [request error] Cannot destructure property 'data' of '((intermediate value)__vite_ssr_import_2__.withAsyncContext(...) , (intermediate value)(intermediate value) , __restore(...) , __temp)' as it is undefined.
  at setup (./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:4338:14)  
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Note: On another endpoint I am getting the lat and lon from the URL itself (without the first API call) and it works totally fine. Your can actually check out out yourself [here](https://sailing-weather.de/forecast/52.45/13.30)

here is the code from the other endpoint which works

```js
<script setup>
const route = useRoute()

const lat = route.params.lat
const long = route.params.long
const name = route.query.name
const url  = 'https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=' + lat + '&longitude=' + long + '&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,surface_pressure,precipitation,weathercode,windspeed_10m,winddirection_10m,windgusts_10m&current_weather=true&windspeed_unit=kn'
const { data: weatherdata, refresh } = await useFetch(url)
</script>
```

Comment: What does the error look like? Did you already try using lat.value and lon.value inside the query of the second API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some things and it is now working. I removed `const {data: locationdata} =`  and now it is working.

Here is my final code:

```js
<script setup>
const route = useRoute()
const id = route.params.id
const lat = ref(null)
const lon = ref(null)
const timezone = ref("")


await useAsyncData("geocode", () =>
  $fetch(`https://geocoding-api.open-meteo.com/v1/get?id=${id}`)
).then((res) => {
  lat.value = res.data.value.latitude
  lon.value = res.data.value.longitude
  timezone.value = res.data.value.timezone
})


const { data: weatherdata, pending } = await useAsyncData("weatherdata", () =>
  $fetch(`https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=${lat.value}&longitude=${lon.value}&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,surface_pressure,precipitation,weathercode,windspeed_10m,winddirection_10m,windgusts_10m&current_weather=true&windspeed_unit=kn&timezone=${timezone.value}`)
).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
</script>
<template>
<pre><code>{{weatherdata}}</code></pre>
</template>
```